# Parameters in link to my action are ignored by Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I suddenly can't seem to pass parameter values as part of my link to a Google Action anymore. This used to work a few months ago, and I don't believe anything changed at our end.

As an example, I have one parameter in my default Welcome intent called "source", type @sys.any.
In the Actions On Google console, I enable the "Link" for actions.intent.MAIN (I can also see the source parameter listed there).

But when using the link, the "source" parameter value never makes it to Dialogflow. I tried links with or without an explicit intent (in theory both should as it's the default intent), but neither work:

https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/000000c0463873a1?intent=actions.intent.MAIN&param.source=mariotest

https://assistant.google.com/services/invoke/uid/000000c0463873a1?param.source=mariotest

In both cases, if I inspect "params" in my fulfilment, it's just { source: '' } - and if I make the source parameter required in Dialogflow, then Actions On Google asks for it, suggesting the value in the link is never received.

Any help or pointers welcome!

Tried link with/without explicit intent, tried with the parameter required or optional, all with the same result.

I'd expect the "source" value passed in the link to be picked up by Dialogflow.

Comment: Your param is in the Default Welcome Intent?

Comment: Hi Nick - yes it's defined in the Default Welcome Intent in Dialogflow, and it's also visible/listed if I look at the Action (via Develop -> Actions -> actions.intent.MAIN) in  the Actions Console.

Comment: Welcome intents don't have parameters, since they're typically not invoked with a user phrase. (In a way they are, but the Event is triggered, not due to the training phrases)

Comment: Ah thanks - we're using Dialogflow in a slightly odd way, as everything is passed through the Welcome intent and then processed elsewhere by some custom NLP and logic, so I guess I need to create a separate intent to use in the link. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah in your case you may want to use the Fallback intent to get the raw text query, or create a separate intent.

Comment: Just to confirm, adding a specific intent for this purpose works, and link parameters are passed along as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll repost the answer just for future reference:

Welcome intents don't have parameters, since they're typically not invoked with a user phrase. (In a way they are, but the Event is triggered, not due to the training phrases)

In your case you may want to use the Fallback intent to get the raw text query, or create a separate intent.